# Why does Handbrake on Mac have subtitle options not available on Windows, and what do they do?

Tags: subtitles, handbrake

The most recent version of Handbrake (1.7.3) has two subtitle burn-in options on Mac that are missing on Windows: "DVD Subtitles" and "Blu-ray Subtitles". The screenshots in the [Handbrake documentation](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.7.0/advanced/audio-subtitle-defaults.html) show this, but there is no comment on the discrepancy, nor is there any explanation for what these options do.

Mac:

[image]

Windows:

[image]

(In fairness, the page has the disclaimer that it's "a draft and may contain incomplete or incorrect information.")

Does anybody know the reason for the difference between the Mac and Windows subtitle options and/or what the extra Mac options are designed to do?

Comment: We can't really answer it - maybe a feature that was not yet ported to the Windows version? Better ask Handbrake Support.